# Select Match Against in Boolean mode is not working fine

Tags: mysql, myisam, full-text-indexing

i have a BD with 3 millions of rows. With id_table, and other field type text (id_songs, name_song).
I have a full text index in 'name_song'.

My select is

```
SELECT * FROM songs 
WHERE MATCH(name_song) AGAINST ('love' in boolean mode)
```

this is ok. But when i run

```
SELECT * FROM songs 
WHERE MATCH(name_song) AGAINST ('one' in boolean mode)
```

this does not show results.

But with

```
select * from songs 
where name_song like '%one%'
```

I have results.

Why don't I have results with one word? and when using like if I have?

Comment: What is the storage engine ? Most likely, `one` is a stopword and thus not being considered for search ad well as indexing

Comment: The engine is MyISAM

Comment: "one" is a stopword for MyISAM. See the full list [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your storage engine is MyISAM. MyISAM has a pretty big Stopword list. Stopword are the words ignored by Full Text parser for indexing. Also, `one` is a Stopword for MyISAM FTS.

Check the full list of stopwords here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes

You can override this list by following these instructions:

> To override the default stopword list for MyISAM tables, set the ft_stopword_file system variable. (See Section 5.1.8, “Server System Variables”.) The variable value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons why a word is ignored in MyISAM's FT:

- The word is too short -- see `ft_min_word_len`, which defaults to 4.
- Stop word
- More than half the rows have that word.  (I'm surprised that `love` was not excluded.)